# Using PHP variables inside SQL statements?

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason I can't pass a var inside a mysql statement. I have a function that can be used for multiple tables. So instead of repeating the code I want to change the table that is selected from like so,

```
function show_all_records($table_name) {

     mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table_name");

etc, etc...

}
```

And to call the function I use 
`show_all_records("some_table")` 
or 
`show_all_records("some_other_table")`

depending on which table I want to select from at the moment. But it's not working, is this because variables can't be passed through mysql statements?

Comment: Obligatory: if the table name is dynamic, you should ensure it matches `/^\w+$/` or similar before interpolating it into SQL, else you may be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 4):

The code you pasted must work. The possible reasons it doesn't are:

- You are using `'SELECT * FROM $table_name'` (single quotes instead of double quotes)
- You misspelled `$table_name`

Try `die("SELECT * FROM $table_name");` and you'll see exactly what's wrong!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table_name") or die(mysql_error());
```

and tell us what does it says. In theory $table_name should be parsed as a string, as it is inside "" and not ''

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine. Can't see why that wouldn't work. Have you connected to the DB properly with mysql_connect() elsewhere in your code? Did the connection get established? Does the user you're connecting as have SELECT permissions on the table you're trying to access?

Answer (score 0):

My recent experience with SQL, PHP, and MySQL showed me that I should write SQL statements like below to have them work, whether inside PHP scripts or from SQL interaction in phpMyAdmin. Otherwise my queries did not work. 
i just modify  same code you have posted above to generalize a bit what i come up with. and give general rules that work.

beware single quotes around any value(record value not a db, table or column name) whether data representing itself or the variable name represent that data. i mean `'` mark. also variable scopes in the language php should be regarded as always, that is another thing.

```
function show_all_records($table_name) {

     mysql_query("SELECT `Username` FROM `$table_name` WHERE `Username` = 'edwin'");

etc, etc...

}
```

In SQL I discovered I should follow the following syntax rules to have my queries work in general:

1. Double-quote all SQL query. i mean the `"` mark.
2. Backquote all database names and table names and column names(column names can be left non-quoted, as well). i mean the  ` (option + comma on Macintosh).
3. Single-Quote all values. i mean the `'` mark.
4. Quote  the variables with the same quotation mark that would be done for their values regarding above three rules.

Comment: could not escape the backquote ` mark in the 2nd one, someone who knows to do may want to edit appropriately.